# What do html5 game buyers/sponsors do with the game?

Tags: html5

I understand there are html5 devs who make contracts with companies: they allow them to use their games for payment.

My question is how do these companies use these games to their benefit: what purposes do they have in forming these contracts and how does "buying" html5 games helps them accomplish it?

For example, if their purpose is generate money, how do they employ the html5 games for this goal?

Comment: Edited the question for narrowing down possible answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, such games are bought by dedicated [browser-based game sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Browser-based_game_websites), which have an existing audience and a method to monetise it.

**Examples**: An [ad-supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adware) business model is very common. In addition, [Miniclip](http://www.miniclip.com/games/en/) sells a virtual currency for in-game items, [Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/) offers that as well as premium memberships, [Armor Games](http://armorgames.com/) does all of the above, but rather unusually also sells T-shirts and plushies.

Comment: I didn't think this would be such a strong method: I thought there was something else I didn't think of, since they pay quite a bit for html5 games (I saw some simple games that could be done in a weekend that generated a couple thousand dollars)